# SIM 7600ei AT command error while sending GET request

Tags: gsm, error, at-commands

I am using the SIM7600ei module with a 4g LTE Sim. I am successfully able to get the IP address.

```
AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"Jio 4G Jio 4G",7

OK

AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 29,99

OK

AT+CGPADDR
+CGPADDR: 1,56.196.171.209
+CGPADDR: 2,0.0.0.0
+CGPADDR: 3,0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0

OK


AT+HTTPINIT
OK
```

But the command AT+HTTPPARA always results in an error.

```
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","www.google.com"
ERROR
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://www.google.com"
ERROR
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://www.iforce2d.net/test.php"
ERROR
```

> AT+HTTPPARA="URL", "http://www.iforce2d.net/test.php"

I am not able to proceed after that. I tried replacing the URL with [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) but still, it immediately shows an error.

Comment: I used my Win10 Chrome to visit: http://www.iforce2d.net/test.php, and got the following response: ***Current UTC: 17 Nov 2020 8:08:09 AM***. Can you use any Chrome (WinPC, Rpi Chrome etc) to make sure your internet connection is OK? Have you tried basic AT commands such as AT ctrl ctrl etc and get OK or similar response? And is your "ip address" local, 192, ... not internet?

Comment: @tlfong01 thank you for responding. As you can see in the screenshot the module has successfully received the IP address and has sent me OK as a response for AT+HTTPINIT. But after that AT+HTTPPARA always results in an error.

Comment: Many thanks for your clarification. I am sorry that I have not studied your screen capture carefully before I asked you the basic setup questions. Actually I have not touched my SIM7600 for a long while and need to refresh my memory by setting up and od basic testing again. I am afraid I might not be able to catch up with you too soon. In the mean time I can only read the user guide and hopefully I can spot anything useful for your troubleshooting. My apologies. Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: Instead of posting a screen capture (which isn't even cropped to the interesting part), you could just have copied the relevant text and inserted it into your question using the "code formatting" button.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have updated the question. Kindly guide if you can find out my error.